# Is there a way to add integers from an arraylist together?

Tags: java

I'm trying to add integers from an arraylist together to allow the person to see how many people are queued for a 1v1. This is my code: `
package me.sub.cPractice.Queue;

```
Main plugin;

public JoinQueue(Main plugin) {
    this.plugin = plugin;
}


@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String s, String[] args) {
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("queuetest")) {
        Player p = (Player) sender;
        new BukkitRunnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (plugin.inqueue.contains(p)) {   
                    String replaced = PlaceholderAPI.setPlaceholders(p, "%server_online%");
                    ScoreHelper helper = ScoreHelper.createScore(p);
                    helper.setTitle("&6&lGoldHQ &r&7┃ &rPractice");
                    helper.setSlot(8, "&7&m---------------------");
                    helper.setSlot(7, "&eOnline: &f" + replaced);
                    helper.setSlot(6, "&eIn Fights: &f" + plugin.infightnumber.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
                    helper.setSlot(5, "&7&m---------------------");
                    helper.setSlot(4, "&eQueued For: &fNoDebuff");
                    helper.setSlot(3, "" + plugin.inqueuenumber.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
                    helper.setSlot(2, "&7&ogoldhq.net");
                    helper.setSlot(1, "&7&m---------------------");
                }
            }
        }.runTaskTimer(plugin, 20L, 20L);
    }
    return false;
}
```

`
I've been stuck on this for a couple hours now, and I haven't been able to find anything that works. It displays it as 1, 1 when I want it to be displayed as 2. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

First of all your question doesn't contain `ArrayList` at all. I guess your problem is at line:

```
helper.setSlot(3, "" + plugin.inqueuenumber.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
```

You can use following code to merge that number's together:

```
helper.setSlot(3, "" + Arrays.stream(plugin.inqueuenumber.toString()
        .replace("[", "")
        .replace("]", "")
        .split(",")
    ).map(Integer::parseInt)
    .reduce(0, (subtotal, current) -> subtotal + current)
)
```

Edit: i noticed that `plugin.inqueuenumber` is that `ArrayList` you have been talking about so also following should work and previous solution is redundant:

```
helper.setSlot(3, "" + plugin.inqueuenumber.stream().reduce(0, (l, r) -> l + r))
```

Comment: Tip: Could use `mapToInt` stead of `map` and then call `sum()` instead of `reduce`, like:  `.mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum()`

Comment: Nice tip, didn't think about that but as mentioned, since he has already numbers stored inside `ArrayList` there is no need to work with number strings. `sum()` method is more appropriate in second case as well.